# Applescript Returned Text not Splitting

Tags: macos, encoding, coding-style, automation, applescript

Ive been playing with applescript for about 2 weeks now, but I have hit a problem
Im trying to create an applescript that reads all the names of the folders on our server.
Then displays them in a drop down menu so that I can select the client.
The problem I have is that it is displaying the result as one selection option as a big sentence and is not separating each client, so they can be selected individually.
so far I have:

```
set theFolder to alias "server:"
tell application "Finder"
    set theText to name of theFolder & return
    set k to 0
    repeat with thisSubfolder in (get folders of theFolder)
        set k to k + 1
        set theText to theText & name of thisSubfolder & return
    end repeat
end tell
set l to {theText}
set l2 to ""
repeat with i in l
    set l2 to l2 & quoted form of i & " "
end repeat
do shell script "/Applications/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog \\
     standard-dropdown --title Title --text Text --items " & l2
set {button, answer} to paragraphs of result
if button is 1 then 
    return item {answer + 1} of l
end if
```

Many thanks

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
set l to {theText}
```

You're just creating a list of one item (your string), which means you end up with this:

```
{"theFolder
folder1
folder2
folder3
"}
```

You're then repeating in that "list," trying to add spaces between the items. But, you don't have a list really. You have a one item list, with return-delimited strings.

The best way to get a list of folder names would be to get them from `System Events`. Notice that in this case, you have to create a list with the name of the first folder as the only item. Otherwise, the `&` operation will join everything together as a string, instead of creating a list.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set l to (name of theFolder as list) & name of folders of theFolder
end tell
```

There are also some syntactical issues that will hurt you later:

**1 != "1"**

CocoaDialog returns a string, with the button number: `"1"`. You are using `if button is 1`. For equality, it should be `if button is "1"`.

**Parentheses are used for grouping, not brackets**

If button is "1", you are returning `item {answer + 1} of l`. I blame Applescript for letting this work when it shouldn't. You're actually creating a list with a number, which then gets coerced by Applescript for the list index. Here are all the steps, assuming `answer` is 0:

1. `item {answer + 1} of l` gets turned into
2. `item {1} of {folder1, folder2, folder3}`
3. Applescript coerces to `item 1 of {folder1, folder2, folder3}`
4. Value returned: `folder1`

Here is a fully updated version of your script:

```
set theFolder to alias "server:"
tell application "System Events"
    set l to {name of theFolder} & name of folders of theFolder
end tell

set args to ""
repeat with i from 1 to (count l)
    set args to args & quoted form of item i of l
    if i < (count l) then
        set args to args & " "
    end if
end repeat

do shell script "/Applications/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog \\
     standard-dropdown --title Title --text Text --items " & args

set {button, answer} to paragraphs of result
if button is "1" then
    return item (answer + 1) of l
end if
```

Comment: Many many thanks to you guys for all your time and help. And thanks for the detailed explanation Darrick, this has been a great help and very informative. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
set l to {theText}
```

to:

```
set l to paragraphs of theText
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Darrick-Herwehe -much more info, I'll upvote for that. I take issue with insisting that using SE is best way. To me, best way is by doing some variation of `"cd '/testing_folder/testhere/';find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \\( ! -name '.' \\) | sed 's/^\\.\\///'"`, which gets name of every folder very quickly.
Speed tests. 1st group uses 6k folders w/ names "folder_1", "folder_2", etc; 2nd group uses 6k randomly named folders & each script run twice in a row.

1st version:

find: 0.07
SE: 0.54
F: 0.40

F: 0.40
SE: 0.33
find (ds): 0.07

2nd v:

find:
 .07
 .06
 
SE:
 0.57
 0.35
 
F:
 0.43
 0.43

Comment: and, as you can see, Finder is often faster than System Events (SE)

Comment: and I should add the caveat that I'm testing on 10.6.8, later OS versions may have differences (looking forward to testing). Also, I accidentally forgot to remove "(ds)" from one of those test 'headings'; "find" is the do shell script version, "F" is Finder, "SE" is System Events. Ok I'm done.